# Illegal capture in lambda expression in c++

Tags: c++, lambda

I have some difficulties writing a valid capture for a rather simple lambda expression. Here is the code I'm trying to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class State { public:
    int i;
    float f;
    State(int i,float f){this->i = i; this->f = f;}
};

typedef State (*FunctionType)(const State &state);


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::vector<FunctionType> funcs;

    funcs.push_back(
        [](const State &state)
        {
            return State(state.i+7,state.f-3.5);
        });

    State s(100,5.5);

    int m = 5;

    funcs.push_back(
        [](const State &state)
        // [=](const State &state)
        // [&](const State &state)
        {
            return State(m,m+0.5);
        });

    for (auto func : funcs)
    {
        std::cout << func(s).i << " " << func(s).f << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it with

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o main
```

I get the following error (and more) indicating that I wasn't able to capture `m`:

```
main.cpp: In lambda function:
main.cpp:32:17: error: ‘m’ is not captured
    return State(m,m+0.5);
                 ^
main.cpp:28:4: note: the lambda has no capture-default
   [](const State &state)
    ^
main.cpp:25:6: note: ‘int m’ declared here
  int m = 5;
      ^
```

Comment: yep, you need to capture `m` (or eveything)

Comment: Your real issue is to store any lambdas into vector. You showed that you can store non capturing lambda (which decay to function pointer), capture in lambda (your commented code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You indeed need one of your commented version to capture `m`

- `[=](const State &state) { return State(m, m + 0.5); }`
- `[&](const State &state) { return State(m, m + 0.5); }`

or explicit capture:

- `[m](const State &state) { return State(m, m + 0.5); }`
- `[&m](const State &state) { return State(m, m + 0.5); }`

But then you have issue with:

```
std::vector<FunctionType> funcs;

funcs.push_back([=](const State &state) { return State(m, m + 0.5); })
```

Capturing lambda cannot decay to function pointer, you need to change

```
typedef State (*FunctionType)(const State &state);
```

into

```
using FunctionType = std::function<State(const State&)>;
```

which can handle lambda

Comment: ... and also actually capture `m` (i.e. `push_back([m](...){...})` or `push_back([&m](...){...})` as appropriate for the purpose).